# Adding extra "\source{something}" command inside table and figure latex environments exported from org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I'm writing a large document in org that I export to PDF through latex. The latex class that I'm using (set in `org-latex-classes`) defines a `\source` command that can be used inside table and figure environments to indicate the source of that material. Something like the code below in latex

```latex
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure.pdf}
\caption{\label{thelabel}The caption.}}
\source{Modified from~\cite{bibkey}.}
\end{figure}
```

In org-mode we can include the figure as (without the `\source command`)

```
#+NAME: thelabel
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width \textwidth
#+CAPTION: \caption{The caption.}
[[figure.pdf]]
```

My question is: How can I tell org-mode to add `\source{whatever}` inside the exported figure environment? Is there something I can pass to `#+ATTR_LATEX: ???` to add what I need inside the environment?

Note: Unfortunately the `\source` command cannot be put inside the caption.

---

Edit: After more research I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573322/org-mode-how-to-use-custom-command-when-exporting-figures) on stackoverflow which is the same question as this one. Essentially, it comes down to either  NickD's answer, or creating a filter, but with the filter solution there does not allow specifying what comes inside the `\source` command and this using `:caption` seems like the only way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `:caption` attribute in `#+ATTR_LATEX:` instead:

```org
#+NAME: thelabel
#+ATTR_LATEX: :width \textwidth :caption \caption{The caption.}\source{the Source}
[[figure.pdf]]
```

The LaTeX file I get reads in part:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/path/to/figure.jpg}
\caption{The caption.}\source{The Source}
\end{figure}
```

which should work as expected.

Comment: That's ingenious and it works. The problem with this solution is that `#+NAME` is ignored and thus I need to repeat the label inside `\caption`. Furthermore, I also want to export to HTML (although in that case I don't care about the `\source`) and thus I need to keep both `#+ATTR_LATEX: :caption ...` and `#+CAPTION`. If I do any change in one of them I have to remember also change the other.

Comment: That's a different question which you should ask separately.